# Using an enum to store boolean strings

Tags: database, postgresql, enums

hopefully someone can give me a bit of guidance here.  I just read a post about why enums are important and I want to make sure I set up my requests in a logical way that won't need rewritten.

I have a user form where every question has three possible answers (Yes, No, Maybe). I have created an enum table in my data base:

```
id   value
1   'True'
2   'False'
3   'Maybe'
```

So I receive the user questionnaire and I get an object like `{q1: true, q2: false, q3: false }`. I convert these booleans to strings and try to post them to my database

```
INSERT INTO questions (q1, q2,q3) VALUES (resp1, resp2, resp3)
```

I am not understanding where the enum table comes in to play.  Is it just there for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have that sort of table, you use 1, 2, 3 in an integer column for the values, not 'true' or 'false'.

Alternatively with PostgreSQL you may create a real enum type with:

```
CREATE TYPE extended_bool as ENUM ('True','False','Maybe');
```

and declare columns of type `extended_bool`. In this case, you don't create the id/value table at all.

Example:

```
create table answers (question text, answer extended_bool);

insert into answers values('The earth is flat', 'False');

select * from answers;
     question      | answer 
-------------------+--------
 The earth is flat | False
```

Or if you prefer the lookup table:

```
create table answers (question text, answer smallint references lookup_table(id));

insert into answers values(
    'The earth is flat',
    (select id from lookup_table where value='False')
);
```

Comment: How does that integer column relate to my values of 'true', 'false', and 'maybe'?

Comment: @tdammon: well, that's right in the enum table of your question. id=1 corresponds to value='True', 2 to 'False', 3 to 'Maybe'.

Comment: So when I want to post new data to a table how do I reference the enum table.  If I already know the values I want to post are 'True', 'False', or 'Maybe'?